# JavaScript navigator.geolocation not executing

Tags: javascript, geolocation, navigator

I'm building a new site and I'm trying to get a client's coords through the browser using navigator.geolocation. It seems to do nothing at all. It doesn't throw an error or call the callback function. I went to another website using geolocation and it worked. My browser doesn't even ask for my permission on  my site. I'm stumped. Thanks for your thoughts.

```
<script>
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getCoor, errorCoor, {maximumAge:60000, timeout:5000, enableHighAccuracy:true});

function getCoor(pos)
{
   var c = pos.coords;
   alert(c.latitude);
}

function errorCoor
{
   alert("FAILED!");
}
</script>
```

EDIT: Here is an exact copy and paste of my script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#c-other-source").hide();
    $("#c-name").focus();
    $("#c-phone").mask('(000) 000-0000');

    $("#c-source").change(function(){
        if ($(this).val() == 7)
        {
            $("#c-other-source").fadeIn("slow", function(){
                $(this).focus();
            });
        }
    });

    $("#c-loc").focus(function(){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getCoor, errorCoor, {maximumAge:60000, timeout:5000, enableHighAccuracy:true});
    });
});

function getCoor(pos)
{
    alert(pos.latitude);
}

function errorCoor()
{
    alert("failed");
}
```

Actually, it is throwing the error function now...

Comment: Now might be a good time to learn [how the browser console works](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers).

Comment: You have a typo in your code: `function errorCoor` needs to be `function errorCoor()`. When I fix this, your code works as expected.

Comment: I know how the browser console works lol. Also, I know the code works for other people...

Comment: If you know how it works then why aren't you using it? `function errorCoor(err) { console.log(err); }`